# Node.js executable can't be found

Tags: nodejs

I am using Ubuntu 16.04. I have installed `node-eclipse` in my system. When I try to create a new project, the `node-eclipse` console show this error

```
Node.js executable can't be found!
null
 /home/melbin/eclipse/jee-neon/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/1001/0/.cp/express/bin/express /tmp/express-work/1469790068444/prjct --ejs 
Unexpected Exception.
```

I have already installed node.js and node express.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the exact command:

[image]

```
  nodeclipse --help
  Usage: nodeclipse [arguments]
  `nodeclipse --help install` for Nodeclipse CLI Installer Help

  Arguments:
 -c, --create <name>      create project folder and prepare it
 -u, --use <template>     use/copy specified template when creating     project
 -p, --prepare            prepare Nodeclipse [Node.js] project for import,    i.e. add needed `.project` file and other `.*`
                  files ('.gitignore', '.jshintrc', '.settings/') if   there is no `.project` yet
 -g, --eclipse_project_general   prepare General Eclipse project for import,  i.e. add only needed `.project` file
 -n, --name [<name>]      project name (default is folder name)
 -h, --help               this help screen
 -v, --version            print nodeclipse CLI's version
 -V, --verbose            be verbose

 Templates are just folders in this project sources:
 hello-world              The famous hello world HTTP server in 6 lines
 hello-coffee             The same server written in CoffeeScript
 hello-typescript         The same server written in TypeScript
 hello-html                       Template with HTML file
 template-gradle-java     Gradle Java project
 template-maven-java      Maven Java project
```

Or

Try to configure path in Preferences ==> Nodeclipse also Install the following packages will help you.

```
sudo apt-get update
npm install -g nodeclipse
```

Look more [here](http://www.nodeclipse.org/#support)